# Completely custom stream operator in c++

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading

I want to create a completely custom stream pipeline for my [video stabilization project](https://github.com/MariusHerget/cimarron) in c++.

The endresult should look like:

```
videofilelocation >> preprocessing() >> analyze() >> stabilize() >> video_out(outputfilename).flush();
```

Therefore, `preprocessing` should accept an input string and load the video, extract frames, etc. Afterward, it should return a custom struct `framevector` which should be passed to `analyze` and so on.

Unfortunately, there is no clear tutorial/explanation on how to implement completely custom stream operators. (Just for `std::ostream`, etc)

How can this be done?

Comment: You overload it like you would overload any other operator. This should be described in your C++ textbook.

Comment: A simple Operator overload did not work on my case. And I did not find ny help online why it does not accept my input or the return value for the next stream...

Comment: note that convention in C++ seems to be the pipe operator aka |   https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/

Comment: As I understood the pipe operator correctly it should be used to to manipulate data. Not to create a pipeline of various steps with loading, saving files, creating Mets data etc. (Correct me if I am wrong - still a noobie in modern c++)

Comment: @NoSense "note that convention in C++ seems to be the pipe operator " - certainly not true. The current Standard Library nowhere uses the pipe (bitwise-or) operator like this.

Comment: One big problem I see is that you want some stages in the pipeline to return a different type, like `string -> framevector -> etc`. If every stage returns a different type, you'd need to write an `operator>>()` with all types hardcoded, and it would be _way_ more work than just writing a sequence of equivalent function calls. Do you want this just for the syntactic look? Or do you want parts of the pipeline to be rearrangeable? In that case, I would suggest you stick to a common type (maybe `videostream`, to act like `iostream`) which is accepted and returned by every `>>` operation.

Comment: after preprocessing the stream should always return a `framevector`. Other metadata like a translation data vector should be passed as an optional parameter via the stream. There is definitely an aesthetic factor to this but also a learning curve about c++ which I want to achieve. Moreover, it should be a preparation for rearrangement and possible multitasking pipelining in the future. A workaround with `iostream` is possible - I think - but not my goal here.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Boost is part of C++(since I never said std::) and also ranges TS uses the same syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unfortunately, there is no clear tutorial/explanation on how to implement completely custom stream operators.

OK. Here's a short one.

the `operator>>` is a binary operator. In order to make it flexible, you will want to write it as a *free function overload*, which means you get to customise its meaning at each step.

In order to get the syntax above, you're looking to build a chain of calls top `operator>>` such that the ouput of one is the first argument to the next.

so `a >> b >> c` really means: `operator>>(operator>>(a, b), c)` note that the output of `a >> b` is the first input of `(a >> b) >> c`.

Here's a very simplified chain which compiles. You will notice I have used value semantics everywhere. If your processing step objects are strict function objects, you could pass them by `const&`. If they carry state over from previous uses, then you'll need overloads for `&&` r-value references.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

// a representation of video data
// note-a value type so it will want to own its actual data through a 
// unique_ptr or similar.
struct video_data
{
};

struct preprocessing
{
    void process(video_data&);
};

struct analyze
{
    void process(video_data&);
};

struct stabilize
{
    void process(video_data&);
};

struct video_out
{
    video_out(std::string const& where);
    void process(video_data&);
};

struct flush
{
    void process(video_out&);
};

// now define the interactions
auto operator>>(std::string const& path, preprocessing proc) -> video_data
{
    video_data dat;
    proc.process(dat);
    return dat;
}

auto operator>>(video_data dat, analyze proc) -> video_data
{
    proc.process(dat);
    return dat;
}

auto operator>>(video_data dat, stabilize proc) -> video_data
{
    proc.process(dat);
    return dat;
}

auto operator>>(video_data dat, video_out proc) -> video_out
{
    proc.process(dat);
    return std::move(proc);
}

auto operator>>(video_out dat, flush proc) -> video_out
{
    proc.process(dat);
    return std::move(dat);
}

// now build a chain
int test(std::string const& videofilelocation, std::string const& outputfilename)
{
    videofilelocation >> preprocessing() >> analyze() >> stabilize() >> video_out(outputfilename) >> flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, I took this as puzzle and got the following small example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// a sample object which is subject of object stream
struct Object {
  // contents
  std::string name;
  int a, b;
  // constructors.
  Object(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) { }
  Object(const std::string &name, int a, int b):
    name(name), a(a), b(b)
  { }
};

// a functor to initialize an object (alternatively)
struct source {
  Object &obj;
  source(Object &obj, int a, int b): obj(obj)
  {
    this->obj.a = a; this->obj.b = b;
  }
  operator Object& () { return obj; }
};

// a clear functor

struct clear {
  clear() = default;
  Object& operator()(Object &in) const
  {
    in.a = in.b = 0;
    return in;
  }
};

// make clear functor applicable to object "stream"

Object& operator>>(Object &in, const clear &opClear)
{
  return opClear(in);
}

// a global instance

static clear reset;

// an add functor

struct add {
  const int da, db;
  add(int da, int db): da(da), db(db) { }
  Object& operator()(Object &in) const
  {
    in.a += da; in.b += db;
    return in;
  }
};

// make add functor applicable to object "stream"

Object& operator>>(Object &in, const add &opAdd)
{
  return opAdd(in);
}

// a display functor

struct echo {
  const std::string label;
  explicit echo(const std::string &label = std::string()):
    label(label)
  { }
  Object& operator()(Object &in) const
  {
    std::cout << label
      << "Object '" << in.name << "' (" << in.a << ", " << in.b << ")\n";
    return in;
  }
};

// make display functor applicable to object "stream"

Object& operator>>(Object &in, const echo &opEcho)
{
  return opEcho(in);
}

// a sink functor (actually not needed)

struct null {
  null() = default;
  void operator()(Object&) const { }
};

// make echo functor applicable to object "stream"

void operator>>(Object &in, const null &opNull) { opNull(in); }

// check it out:
int main()
{
  Object obj("obj1", 12, 34);
  // either use obj as source
  obj
    >> echo("before add(-2, -4): ")
    >> add(-2, -4)
    >> echo("after add(-2, -4): ")
    >> reset
    >> echo("after reset: ")
    >> null();
  // or a source operator
  source(obj, 11, 22)
    >> echo("before add(11, -11): ")
    >> add(11, -11)
    >> echo("after add(11, -11): ");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
before add(-2, -4): Object 'obj1' (12, 34)
after add(-2, -4): Object 'obj1' (10, 30)
after reset: Object 'obj1' (0, 0)
before add(11, -11): Object 'obj1' (11, 22)
after add(11, -11): Object 'obj1' (22, 11)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/842500ab3f8a549f)</kbd>

The basic principle is inspired by stream operators:

The `operator>>`s get an `Object` reference, process the object (changing its state) and return the reference. This allows to pass an object created in most left argument of expression through the chain of operators.

To apply "function like manipulators", functor classes are used in combination with a respective `operator>>`.

To provide "manipulators" which can be used without `()`, a global instance is needed additionally.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
class FileLocation        {};
class PreProcessedData    {};

class PreProcessingAction {
    public:
        PreProcessedData doStuff(FileLocation const& file) const
        {
            return PreProcessedData{};
        }
};

PreProcessingAction preprocessing() {
    return PreProcessingAction{};
}

PreProcessedData operator>>(FileLocation const& file, PreProcessingAction const& action)
{
    return action.doStuff(file);
}

int main()
{
    FileLocation   location;

    location >> preprocessing();
}
```

To be honest this seems to complicate the code more than help.

Would it not be easier to do something like this:

```
Data     file            = readData("InputName");
Data     preProcData     = preprocessing(file);
Data     analysedData    = analyze(preProcData);
Data     stabalizedData  = stabilize(analysedData);

Output   output("OutputName");    
output << stabalizedData;
```